# timing floating point calculation with clock_gettime in C, time keeps changing?

Tags: c, floating-point, timing

I'm trying to calculate the time of a piece of code (floating point multiplications) using `clock_gettime()`. I randomly generate 10 arrays of 100000 floats and then multiply them all together, ten at a time. What I want to do is measure the time it takes to perform ten floating point multiplies, then add that time value to the total time, and then print it all out at the end.

I thought it was all working, but I discovered that if I remove my `printf()` statements from the while loop, the time decreases from `28125692` to `17490394` nanoseconds! This shouldn't be happening. I placed the `clock_gettime()` calls at the beginning and end of the floating point multiplications, so theoretically, the `printf()` statement should not effect the elapsed time!

Any ideas?  Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    float alpha[100000];
    float bravo[100000];
    float charlie[100000];
    float delta[100000];
    float echo[100000];
    float foxtrot[100000];
    float golf[100000];
    float hotel[100000];
    float india[100000];
    float juliet[100000];
    float max;
    long long num_calcs;
    struct timespec start_time;
    struct timespec end_time;
    int diff_seconds;
    long diff_nanoseconds;
    long long total_calcs;
    long long total_seconds;
    long long total_nanoseconds;

    num_calcs = 100000;

    max = 1000.0;

    printf("\n%lld floating point calculations requested.", num_calcs);
    printf("\nGenerating random floating point values...");

    //initialize random seed
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    //generate random floating point values
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        alpha[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        bravo[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        charlie[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        delta[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        echo[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        foxtrot[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        golf[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        hotel[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        india[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
        juliet[i] = ((float) rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX)) * max;
    }
    printf("done!");

    printf("\nRunning %lld floating point multiplications...", num_calcs);

    //run calculations
    i = 0;
    total_calcs = 0;
    total_seconds = 0;
    total_nanoseconds = 0;

    while (total_calcs < num_calcs)
    {
        printf("\n\nRunning 10 calculations...");
        //do 10 multiplications
        //start the timer
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start_time) < 0)
        {
            printf("\nclock_gettime for start_time failed, exiting...");
            return -1;
        }
        alpha[i] * bravo[i] * charlie[i] * delta[i] * echo[i] *
        foxtrot[i] * golf[i] * hotel[i] * india[i] * juliet[i];
        //stop the timer
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end_time) < 0)
        {
            printf("\nclock_gettime for end_time failed, exiting...");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("done!");
        total_calcs = total_calcs + 10; //increase total calculations
        i++;                //increment array index

        //show timing statistics
        printf("\nSTART TIME tv_sec:  %d", (int) start_time.tv_sec);
        printf("\nSTART TIME tv_nsec: %ld", start_time.tv_nsec);
        printf("\nEND TIME tv_sec:    %d", (int) end_time.tv_sec);
        printf("\nEND TIME tv_nsec:   %ld", end_time.tv_nsec);

        //calculate time it took to run 10 floating point caculcations
        if ((end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec) < 0)
        {
            diff_seconds = end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec - 1;
            diff_nanoseconds = 1000000000 + end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec;
        }
        else
        {
            diff_seconds = end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec;
            diff_nanoseconds = end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec;
        }

        //add elapsed time for the last 10 calculations to total elapsed time
        total_seconds = total_seconds + diff_seconds;
        total_nanoseconds = total_nanoseconds + diff_nanoseconds;

        printf("\nPerformed 10 floating point multiplications in %d seconds and %ld nanoseconds.", diff_seconds, diff_nanoseconds);
        printf("\nPerformed %lld floating point multiplications in %lld seconds and %lld nanoseconds.", total_calcs, total_seconds, total_nanoseconds);
    }
    printf("done!");

    printf("\nPerformed %lld floating point multiplications in %lld seconds and %lld nanoseconds.\n", total_calcs, total_seconds, total_nanoseconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As `alpha[i] * bravo[i] * charlie[i] * delta[i] * echo[i] * foxtrot[i] * golf[i] * hotel[i] * india[i] * juliet[i];` is a no-op, an optimizing compiler will omit this from the executable.

Comment: There are many reasons why `printf` statements in the `for` but outside the code you are timing may affect performance. Most likely because they cause extra cache misses.

Comment: Your nanosecond amounts are very exact. Are those the results of running each implementation just once? When talking about the difference between 28 and 17 ms, it could just as easily be caused by a slightly different workload on the CPU or state of the cache. You need to run and average hundreds of tests before determining that one implementation is in fact slower than another.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Those specific numbers are from two tests but I have run it over and over again and gotten similar results.

I'm using gcc with no optimizing options, wouldn't it not optimize the code?

Comment: Suggest running with _nothing_ between the 2 `clock_gettime()` calls to assess the time associated with leaving the first and entering the second call.

Comment: @pmg I think you are correct.  I dumped the assembly code and noticed no FMULS instructions (it's an ARM machine) between the two clock_gettime calls.  But when I made the program print out the resulting floating-point product, the code changed drastically and there were a lot of FMULS.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm honestly surprised you can get a way with 4MB worth of `float`s on your stack...

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
    alpha[i] * bravo[i] * charlie[i] * delta[i] * echo[i] *
    foxtrot[i] * golf[i] * hotel[i] * india[i] * juliet[i];
```

is a no-op. An optimizing compiler will omit this from the executable.

To make it work, try adding the result to another variable and print the sum at the end of the program.